# flex and bison:C++ class

Tags: c++, bison

When I embed a list* pointer into the bison parser, the compiler reports a error that 'list' does not name a type. Here is some necessary pieces; if you need, I can post all code. I am using the latest version of bison and flex.

```
parser.l
%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
extern void yyerror(const char *);
extern int yylex();
char* outchar;
char* mychars;
unsigned int line_number=1;
%}
%option nounput 
%option noyywrap
%option noinput
%%
"automaton"     {return AUTOMATON;}
"var"       {return VAR;}
"synclabs"  {return SYNCLABS;}
"initially"     {return INITIALLY;}
"loc"       {return LOC;}
"while"     {return WHILE;}
"wait"      {return WAIT;}
"when"      {return WHEN;}
"do"        {return DO;}
"sync"      {return SYNC;}
"goto"      {return GOTO;}
"end"       {return END;}
"forbidden"     {return FORBIDDEN;}
"true"      {return TRUE;}
"TRUE"      {return TRUE;}
"false"     {return FALSE;}
"FALSE"     {return FALSE;}

"="         {return EQ2;}
"=="        {return EQ;}
">="        {return GE;}
"<="        {return LE;}
"'"         {return PRIM;}
":="        {return ASSIGN;}

([0-9]+)(("."[0-9]+)?)((([eE])([+-]?)([0-9]+))?)  {yylval.mystring = strdup(yytext);   return INT;}

[-+<>*/&|(){}:;,.=!]|"["|"]" {return *yytext;}

(["$""?"a-zA-Z]|[_])("$"|"?"|[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[_]|[~])* { yylval.mystring =   strdup(yytext); return IDENT; }


"/*"([^*]|("*"+[^*/]))*"*"+"/" /* skip comment */
"//".*                         /* skip comment XS*/
"--".*                         /* skip comment */
[\n] { ++line_number; 

}
[ \t\r]                      
%%

parser.y
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<list>

using namespace std;

extern int yylex();
extern unsigned int line_number;
void yyerror(const char *msg)
{       
        printf("Parse error in line %d: ", line_number);
        printf("%s\n", msg);
}
Automaton *aut; 
int var_count=0;
string *s;

%}

%union{
char * mystring;
list* s;

};


%token AUTOMATON
%token VAR
%token SYNCLABS
%token INITIALLY
%token LOC
%token WHILE
%token WAIT
%token WHEN
%token DO
%token SYNC
%token GOTO
%token END
%token ASSIGN
%token FORBIDDEN
%token TRUE
%token FALSE
%token <mystring> INT
%token <mystring> IDENT

//%nonassoc '(' ')'
%left  '&'
%left GE LE EQ EQ2
%left '+' '-'
%left '!'
%left '(' ')'
%left PRIM

%%  

program:
commands
;
%%

compile result:
g++ -O2 -w -c -I .  -g -O2 -o lex.yy.o lex.yy.c
In file included from parser.l:4:0:
parser.y:23:2: error： ‘list’does not name a type
```

Comment: But I have seen someone uses list and user defined class pointer in a union.

Comment: No compiler errors here. Please post a minimal complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: If you want to compiler a `.c` file as C++ you need to say `-x c++`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's pretty clear, your lexer code (i.e. parser.l) doesn't have `#include <list>` or `using namespace std;`

BTW a tip, if you get fed up of the quirks of flex and bison then take a look at [Lemon](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/lemon/) as a replacement for bison, it's simple and pretty good, and it will also help with your situation of using pointers in your '%union'. Also take a look at [Ragel](http://www.complang.org/ragel/) as a replacement for flex, it's more complex but brilliant.

Comment: But after I add the recommended code to the lexer code, the error is still reported.

Comment: You need to add it before `#include <parser.tab.h>` because the offending definition is in that file. BTW you are using `list` without the argument list.